# Implementing Search in ListView builder

Tags: flutter, search

I'm new to coding and I'm trying to make my own app. I'm trying to have a search feature for my listview building but I am having trouble implementing the search. I've tried different tutorials and youtube videos but I can't seem to implement it correctly.

here's the dummy data i'm using

class.dart

```
class Disease {
  String id, title;
  List<String> diagnostics;
  List<String> management;
  Disease({this.id, this.title, this.diagnostics, this.management});
}
```

data.dart

```
import 'class.dart';

class Data {
  static List<Disease> disease = [
    Disease(
      id: '1', 
      title: 'Dengue', 
      diagnostics: [
      'CBC, Plt',
      'Dengue NS1 if less than 4 days',
      'Dengue Duo if more than 4 days from onset of symptoms',
    ], management: [
      'Hydration',
      'No Dark Colored Foods',
      'aoiushdioaushd',
    ]),
    Disease(
      id: '1',
      title: 'Typhoid Fever',
      diagnostics: [
        'CBC, Plt',
        'Dengue NS1 if less than 4 days',
        'Dengue Duo if more than 4 days from onset of symptoms',
      ],
      management: [
        'Hydration',
        'No Dark Colored Foods',
        'aoiushdioaushd',
      ],
    )
  ];
}
```

and my home page where search is implemented

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:yellow_book/utils/class.dart';
import 'package:yellow_book/utils/data.dart';

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title = ''}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  var disease = Data.disease;

  TextEditingController editingController = TextEditingController();

  final duplicateItems = List<String>.generate(10000, (i) => "Item $i");

  var items = List<String>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    items.addAll(duplicateItems);
    super.initState();
  }

  void filterSearchResults(String query) {
    List<String> dummySearchList = List<String>();
    dummySearchList.addAll(duplicateItems);
    if (query.isNotEmpty) {
      List<String> dummyListData = List<String>();
      dummySearchList.forEach((item) {
        if (item.contains(query)) {
          dummyListData.add(item);
        }
      });
      setState(() {
        items.clear();
        items.addAll(dummyListData);
      });
      return;
    } else {
      setState(() {
        items.clear();
        items.addAll(duplicateItems);
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          TextField(
            onChanged: (value) {
              filterSearchResults(value);
            },
            controller: editingController,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: "Search",
              prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                  Radius.circular(0.0),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: disease.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Card(
                  child: ListTile(
                    onTap: () {},
                    title: Text(disease[index].title),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

please help. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Currently your `ListView` is based on the `disease` property in your `StatefulWidget` and you don't change this list in any way (add or remove entries). Your `filterSearchResults` function as well as in `initState` you work with your `items` property so you should reference this one in your `ListView` or change your overall logic to work on your `disease` property.

So for now you can change your `ListView` to:

```dart
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: items.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return Card(
      child: ListTile(
        onTap: () {},
        title: Text(items[index]),
      ),
    );
  },
),
```

This will show all `items` entries as `ListTile` and you should be able to search them. If you want to make this work on your `disease` property, you need to change your functions to make use of the `disease` property instead of `items`.